# Facebook is not displaying my information properly while sharing a page.How to solve?

Tags: php, html, facebook, facebook-graph-api, unicode

I have developed and hosted a website weeks ago. Now I facing a problem which is when I share a page(who shows different videos according to id) from my website in Facebook, It does not fetch title, sometimes it does not even shows image and most importantly it does not show my actual description instead it shows some random Japanese text(I don't have any relation with Japanese text).

But most interesting thing is, it works perfectly fine for some videos. But trust me I used every tags that Facebook needs `og:url,og:type,og:title,og:description,og:image`

```
$vid = $_GET['info'];
$qry = "SELECT * FROM videos WHERE vid = '$vid' ";
$query=mysql_query($qry);
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
if($numrows >= 1){
    $arr = mysql_fetch_array($query);
    $current_url = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

    echo "<meta property=\"og:url\"           content=\"$current_url\" />
                  <meta property=\"og:type\"          content=\"website\" />  
                  <meta property=\"og:title\"         content=\"$arr[vid_title]\" />
          <meta property=\"og:description\"   content=\"$arr[description]\" />
          <meta property=\"og:image\"         content=\"http://www.drissho.com/vid_photo/$arr[photo]\" />

    <title>Drissho | $arr[vid_title]</title>
    <meta charset=\"UTF-16\"  content=\"$arr[vid_title]\"/>
    <meta http-equiv=\"description\"  content=\"$arr[description]\">`enter code here`
    <meta  http-equiv=\"keywords\"  content=\"$arr[vid_title]\">";
}
```

As I just said sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't, I will provide links of my website so that you can better understand my problem, Just click "Share this video on Facebook" button below video iframe.

The link below works just fine :

http://www.drissho.com/tv/funny/c76e9c9707d7673869c26bc9c6b66c5d

But the link below isn't working(displaying Japanese text) :

http://www.drissho.com/tv/cool/8fc5ede083f6448d08c6f129b9d6d8f1

I also used Facebook url debugger, for some videos it says `og:title` missing, but for some videos it works fine.

Comment: *"I am going to die. Please help"* - A bit dramatic. Your life won't end because of it.

Comment: For some reason, Facebook’s scraper doesn’t get to see your meta tag, because it is [just presented with a document that contains only a Content-Type meta tag](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/echo?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.drissho.com%2Ftv%2Fcool%2F8fc5ede083f6448d08c6f129b9d6d8f1)

Comment: @CBroe: how can I solve this ?

Comment: Well, you’ll need to investigate why your server/your system responds that way – no one here can do that for you from the “outside.”

Comment: Try moving the `<base href="/" />` element from the top of the page into the `<head>` section where it belongs.